# PHP Submit two form actions via one form to SQL/FTP server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

Need your help and suggestions please. I have a form that submits data to MySQL database and images to database + Sql. The problem i'm facing is that I can submit data successfully using  method but cannot submit the images because it requires `<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="myFile.php">`. The same goes for images. I can submit the images successfully to ftp but then the data won't post using `<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="myFile.php">`.

I've tried every possible method in the book and researched so many sites. I've tried approaching this with Ajax, Jquery (Two forms, two actions and one submit button). Please please point me in the right direction.

My code: Form.php (I currently ended up making two forms):

```
<form method="post">
    <input name="haz1" type="text" value="<?php echo $haz1; ?>">
    <input name="haz2" type="text" value="<?php echo $haz2; ?>">
    <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="SAVE FORM">
    </form>

    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="myFile.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000" />
    <input name="haz_img1" type="file" id="img" />
    <br>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="SAVE FORM">
</form>
```

myFile.php

```
<?php

    require("../db.php");
    $id =$_REQUEST['id'];

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM haz3 WHERE id  = '$id'");
    $test = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    if(!$result)
    {
        die("Error: Data not found..");
    }

    $haz_img1 = $test['haz_img1'];
    $haz1 = $test['haz1'];
    $haz2 = $test['haz2'];

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $haz_img1_save = $_POST['haz_img1'];
        $haz1_save = $_POST['haz1'];
        $haz2_save = $_POST['haz2'];

        $remote = "hazard-access/";
        $target1 = $remote . basename( $_FILES['haz_img1']['name']);
        $haz_img1 = ($_FILES['haz_img1']['name']);
        move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['haz_img1']['tmp_name'], $target1 );

        mysql_query("UPDATE haz3 SET haz_img1 = '$haz_img1_save',haz1 ='$haz1_save',haz2 ='$haz2_save' WHERE id = '$id'")
        or die(mysql_error()); 
        echo "";
    }

    mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

I'm trying to submit the data and files together. I do not know if this is possible with one form or two forms or whether I should async via ajax.

I tried this approach:

```
function sendData()
{
    var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('form1'));

    $.ajax({
        url: 'h1_temp.php',  //Server script to process data
        type: 'POST',  //POST or GET
        xhr: function()
        {  // Custom XMLHttpRequest
            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            return myXhr;
        },
        data: formData,  //form data
        //Options to tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type.
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not sending all data to only one script?

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="haz1" type="text" value="<?php echo $haz1; ?>" />
    <input name="haz2" type="text" value="<?php echo $haz2; ?>" />

    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000" />
    <input name="haz_img1" type="file" id="img" />
    <br>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="SAVE FORM">
</form>
```

You than just save the image in `form.php` (maybe using the myFile.php script).

Comment: I have the same problem tho. The Form actions are conflicting with each other because the submit button is common.

Comment: Where are "the action" conflicting? I think your example code is missung something (e.g. I don't see the necessary "id" request param).

Comment: Is there another way besides the one in my code to Request id. I am trying to post all data to the particular id in the database.

Comment: Let me simplify my question. I am trying to use a form to update the data and images of a particular id in the databse. Right now I can only do one of each and not both together. I think it is the way i'm Requesting id..

Comment: I still don't see where you send the ID from the form to the PHP script. Did you get some error? What is the output of `print_r($_POST)` for your request?